# Have some 2TB partition for a directory

Tags: partition, vmware

I have 4 2TB HDD on a VmWare ESXi 5.1 server.

I have httpd on /var/www/html directory on a Centos VM. can I have full size of 4 HDD (8TB) on this directory?

Or I must mount every HDD to seperate directory?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Each filesystem (ergo disk) can be mounted as RAID/JBOD or in separated directories so there are too many correct answers.

Comment: I dont want separate directory, because on that way I must manage files in different disk... I want have single partition mounted on single directory, and store all of my files there. link /var/www/html for web server access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can create a LVM volume and then add these devices to the volume. Once you have the pool of disks in the LVM, you can then create logical volumes within it, which could then be mounted under `/var/www/html`.

Specific steps can be seen here in this tutorial on LVM.

- [A Beginner's Guide To LVM](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm)

I caution you that this approach can be dangerous because by creating a single LVM, if any one of the disks fails, you'll lose the entire volume group. It's similar to a RAID0 in your exposure to risk.

If I were you I'd create a RAID5 or RAID6 and put the disks into that RAID. Then create the LVM volume group on top of the RAID.

Steps for setting up the RAID can be found here:

- [RAID setup - kernel.org](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup)

Comment: Thanks for your full answer.But vmware 5.1 have 2TB limit for maximum size of of a Virtual drive (if I say true).
I can not creat other raids,because I nee full possible of my drives,I must risk and I have offline backup of my datas.

and its possible use this? : mhddfs http://romanrm.ru/en/mhddfs

Comment: @IrajTaghlidi - Great! If you feel your questions been resolved, please mark this as the accepted answer so that others know your issue's been resolved.